# Non-exhaustive pattern in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I need to implement function that inserts two elements in the head of the List but I get

```
Exception: <interactive>:7:5-41: Non-exhaustive patterns in function addTwoElements
```

The code of the the function is following

```
addTwoElements a b [xs]= a : b : [xs]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pattern like `[xs]` means you match only with lists that contain *exactly one* element (and that element is `xs`).

You can here use a variable `xs` for example and write the `addTwoElements` function like:

```
addTwoElements :: a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
addTwoElements a b xs = a : b : xs
```